Reference for pinout out of Segger EDU target board?
I'm in the middle of a board design where the processor uses the segger ten pin pinout. For example this debugger from adafruit. I can't find a good pinout of the connector that shows the orientation in layout. Their website documentation doesn't show it as far as I can tell, and I don't see it in their forums, and their ask a question keeps telling me my captcha is wrong! Anyway does anyone have a definitive answer?  I was just in review and realized I didn't know if the connector goes 1-2, 3-4 or 1-10, 2-9 etc.
I found a pogo pin version with the pinout like this, but of course I did the opposite on my board (odds on the left, evens on the right).

Anyway, any advice here is appreciated. I really don't want to make this.

Segger specifies the 9-Pin Cortex-M Adapter Pinout as follows:

Source: Segger 9-Pin Cortex-M Adapter
This is also compliant to the ARM specification:

Source: Cortex-M Debug Connectors

The debugger you've linked is Cortex-M compliant, that's why I'm using the Cortex-M pinout as reference.
